# Comparing different step functions

Tags: time-series, distributions, discrete-data

I measured the appearance of certain events over time in different conditions and I would like to know whether there is a difference between the happening of these events.

I thought of plotting the events as cumulative curves, such as:

```
# The times at which events occurr
times.1 <- c(0, 5, 15, 20, 25, 33, 40, 50)
times.2 <- c(0, 10, 20, 21, 35, 40, 56)
# The number of events
num.1 <- c(0, 10, 30, 22, 11, 3, 8, 10)
num.2 <- c(0, 5, 3, 20, 10, 8, 5)
plot(times.1, cumsum(num.1), t="s", col="red", lwd=2,
     xlab="Time", ylab="Number of events", las=1)
points(times.2, cumsum(num.2), t="s", col="blue", lwd=2)
```

This gives me this nice graph:
[image: cumulative graph]

How would analyse whether there are differences between the two conditions, knowing that I have 5-10 measurements for each group?

Also, I would like to represent an average curve for each condition, but the events do not always happen at the same time, so I find myself a little bit stuck as I cannot think of some sensible way of "averaging" discrete non uniform data.

I am interested both in changes in the number of events and in the timing (e.g.: a certain condition may reach the same number of events but slower than the other)

Comment: what do you mean by wanting to know the difference 'between the happening'?

Comment: @rbatt: well, know the difference between the appearence of events in the different conditions. Looking at the graph one would say that one conditions has more events and that they start appearing earlier in time.